# Purely geometric proof of inverse hyperbolic trigonometric functions derivatives.

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, proof-writing, hyperbolic-functions

What is a purely geometric proof of the derivatives of the inverse hyperbolic trig functions? I saw this post by John Hilbert [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3759552/purely-geometric-proof-of-inverse-trigonometric-functions-derivatives). and a answer from Blue [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757241/930105). That gave me a new question **What are some purely geometric proofs of inverse hyperbolic trigonometric functions derivatives?**

I do not want to use the fact that $\cos(xi)=\cosh(x)$ and then using implicit differentiation because I already know how to use that method. I want it to be proved using the geometry of a hyperbola.

Comment: do you know how to prove the regular hyperbolic trig derivatives?